# C# Arduino headtracking MPU6050

Tags: c#, math, arduino, fft

i'm working on an application that can help people with disabilites to uses the computer. The application reads values from Arduino+MPU6050 (wich is positioned over the head), and converts it into position. The values from serial ports are like "x,y", and the scale of this values goes from -16000 to +16000.

I processing this values in my computemethod (i report it at bottom of this post). Everything works fine, but i have a problem. If the person that use this software/hardware has some type of muscle spams or tics, the software is too precise and moves the mouse. I want to eliminate this chronical movement...how can i do this?

This is the code of computePosition..

```
public void computePosition()
        {
            data = connection.readSeriaLine();
            words = data.Split(',');
            yaw = words[0];
            pitch = words[1];
            Int32.TryParse(pitch, out posiY);
            Int32.TryParse(yaw, out posiX);
            posiX = posiX / headSensitivity; 
            posiX = posiX - globalPosiX;
            posiY = posiY / headSensitivity;
            posiY = posiY - globalPosiY;
            int signX = Math.Sign(posiX);
            int signY = Math.Sign(posiY);
            int positionX = Cursor.Position.X;
            int positionY = Cursor.Position.Y;
            Cursor.Position = new Point(positionX + (signX * movementSensitivity), positionY + (signY * movementSensitivity));
     }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommmend you use data processing of movement artefacts in firmware. Sicknesses, like Parkinson desease have tremor at frequencies 1-20 Hz. You can use programmatical filters with adaptation to determined frequency.

To calculate frequency use Fourier transform for accelerometer and gyro raw data.

So, in general you should:

- store raw data of sensors in corresonding arrays
- do FFT
- process filtering for the arrays (cut off dominant frequencies from FFT)
- send data to motion processing and then to PC

You can try to do the same on X,Y coordinates in winform app. What way you will use depends on what artefacts you encounter in each particular case. You may even need different filter's setups for warious deseases or self-learning algorithms for each patient.

P.S. You may receive more answers if mark the question with "math" (or similar) tag. Because it lays not in C# or Arduino field.

---

Update.

Before doing programming i would recommend you to do some research work. First of all you need to gather data from the sensors weared on a man with certain desease. You need at least 30-60 seconds of data containing ticks movement artefacts. Write data in 3 columns:

time in ms | x position | y position

Then go to [labchart reader download page](http://www.adinstruments.com/products/labchart-reader), download and install it. Open file with data and do "spectrum" command/view on both X and Y. This will give you info about frequencies which are present (both artefacts and "good" movements). I suppose movement artefact frequencies have bigger amplitude. Remember those frequencies.

Then do "digital filter"-> "band stop" command. And cut off frequencies from previous step. I hope that after this proccessing you will see good charts without artefacts.

Then you can do programming. Implementing FFT and digital filtering is not really hard. For FFT you can use Aforge.Math library.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for your reply! I'm not very expert in this field, do you have some link or example to help me? for example, i've implement this type of solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQC73LKnJck, but it's not useful to me, because i don't know how to filter "little" movement...

Comment: Vladimir, you are awesome! I will try  tomorrow.... do you think the result in this video is good? The figure on the right is the combination of gyro/acc with kalmann filter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmd6CVrlHOM